# How do I delete all subscribers list in child BU without affecting Parent BU in SFMC Enterprise 1.0

Tags: marketing-cloud, list

Can someone please help with the below issue.

I have a scenario, we had a new child BU with zero subscribers in all subscribers list ( SFMC Enterprise 1.0 )

I have imported few contacts manually into the all subcribers list of Child BU. Now, the client wants me to delete all the all subcribers list in child BU. My question is will the deletion of all subscribers list in child BU reflect/affect the all subscribers list in Parent BU?

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The All Subscribers list is a data structure shared across all BUs. Therefore, the subscribers are visible for all business units.

Also, any action on the list on a child BU will be reflected in the parent BU.

However, if in your context you need to keep visibility restricted to the parent level or for certain users (from the parent business unit), you can set the permission for "all subscribers" to 'deny' for the level BU users :

[image]

Comment: Can you confirm this is true for Enterprise 1.0? Enterprise 1.0 has a few differences from 2.0 with regards to the All Subscribers, this may be one of them.

Comment: Hi Zak

Thanks for the information. Just got to know that  Enterprise 1.0 has an isolated data schema, meaning that each business unit in E1.0 is 100% isolated from each other. So deleting the ALL subscribers List at a Child level will not delete it from the Parent Level.

Answer (score 0):

You can Filter Subscribers in a Child BU: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_define_a_subscriber_filter.htm&type=5